# Check if a string has space between all its letters

Tags: python

Hi I need help to do this:
given that I have a string contains spaces and lower case letters only, I need to check if all the letters in the string separated from each other by at least one space. if the string follow this, print "is separated", otherwise print is not separated.
thank you :)

Comment: What is your sample Input/Output?

Comment: Please share a sample input and your expected output. You must provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very crude and it is unclear what you want:

```
s1 = "t his will fail"
s2 = "t h     i s s e p a d"

def is_spaced(s):
    prev = s[0]
    result = "is spaced"
    for c in s[1:]:
        if not c.isspace() and not prev.isspace():
            result = "not spaced"
            break
        prev = c

    return result

print(is_spaced(s1))
print(is_spaced(s2))
```

Outputs:

```
not spaced
is spaced
```

Comment: If you think the question is unclear, don't answer it, vote to close it as "unclear what your asking" (and eventually ask for details in a comment)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string into a list on spaces, then find out the max length of each space in a single command. If every character is spaced out, the maximum length of each element in the list will be one. If there are multiple letters together, the max will be > 1.

`len(max(teststring.split(' '), key=len))`

So simply this becomes:

```
if len(max(teststring.split(' '), key=len)) == 1:
    print("is separated")
else:
    print("is not separated")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `isspace()` fuction,it doesnt take any parameters and it returns true and false.If u want to check if a certain `string` has space between it use `string.isspace()`

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on spaces, then check the length of each component.

```
demo='a b c d ef'
if all([len(item)<2 for item in demo.split(' ')]):
    print('is separated')
else:
    print('not separated')
```

`demo.split(' ')` splits the list on a space. giving `['a','b','c','d','ef']`

`[len(item)<2 for item in demo.split(' ')]` runs through the above list and checks the length of each component. It returns True if the length is less than 2 and False otherwise. For this example, this gives `[True,True,True,True,False]`

`all([len(item)<2 for item in demo.split(' ')])` uses all() to check if all the booleans in the list are True. It returns true if everything is True, and False otherwise.

Comment: Python has a `all()` function builtin already, no need for numpy here.

Comment: Thanks for that. Have edited numpy out.